# CLI asks username and password for github

Tags: github

burat.hurman@US-MBP-X2V6NR testrepo % git push

Username for 'https://github.com': hurmanb

Password for 'https://urhanmc@github.com':

I'm trying my github account password but it doesn't work.
I have checked my password several times, my github account password is correct.

can anybody knows how to solve it?

Comment: I'd recommend you use ssh key instead of https if possible.  But if you need / want to use https, read https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/about-authentication-to-github#https .

Comment: You have to use a personal access token instead of your account password.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use personal access token instead of password; you can create a personal access token from here: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/managing-your-personal-access-tokens